# How to use Webpack alias with TypeScript Declaration

Tags: typescript, webpack

I am writing a NPM package with TypeScript but I could not find a way to convert Webpack alias in TypeScript Declaration.

**webpack.config.js**

```
{
  // ...more Webpack configurations
  resolve: {
  extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
  alias: {
    "@": resolvePath("src")
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // More options
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

I am using `babel-loader` with `@babel/preset-typescript` but it does not output declaration files.

`tsc --emitDeclarationOnly` emits declaration files but it does not replace `@/` with correct path. Same for `ts-loader`.

I am able to get it working in Jest with `moduleNameMapper`. If I can get it working building declaration files, I not longer need to write somethings like `../../../../model`.

Most of the answers I found online is about compiling JavaScript files, which I don't have a problem with. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you share a repo on github with your current example and I might be able to help?

Comment: @EvenStensberg https://github.com/joshuaavalon/webpack-alias-typescript-declaration-example When you run `npm run build`, you can see `index.d.ts` has `export * from "@/bar";`

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin ?

Comment: @EvenStensberg That plugin does not solve the problem. That plugin convert `paths` in `tsconfig.json` to `alias` in `webpack.config.js` which I have already written. The problem is most of the loader use tsc to create type declaration which does not convert `paths`.

Comment: Don't have any answer to this other than giving you urls: https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/type-safe-es2015-module-import-path-aliasing-with-webpack-typescript-and-jest-fe461347e010

Comment: @EvenStensberg I have read that already but it has nothing to do with emitting declaration files. It is about how to configure Jest.

Comment: Try `'@': path.join(__dirname, 'src')` on webpack.config.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally find a solution. You need `ttypescript` and `typescript-transform-paths`. You add the following to `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`

```
"plugins": [
  { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths", "afterDeclarations": true }
]
```

and run

```
ttsc --emitDeclarationOnly
```

I wrote an [article](https://medium.com/@joshuaavalon/webpack-alias-in-typescript-declarations-81d2b6c0dcd6) on this.

Comment: It helped me just today. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue and I managed to solve it like this.

Install [ts-patch](https://github.com/nonara/ts-patch) and the "typescript-transform-paths" starts working.

Repo here:
https://github.com/worldpwn/tsc-declaration-alias-issue

package.json

```
{
  "name": "a",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "ts-patch install -s",
    "build": "tsc",
    "build-webpack": "webpack --mode=production"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "ts-patch": "^2.0.1",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^3.5.2",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2",
    "typescript-transform-paths": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.64.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "declaration": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "paths": {
      "@alias/*": [
        "alias-folder/*"
      ],
    },
    "plugins": [
      {
        "transform": "typescript-transform-paths",
        "afterDeclarations": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/index.ts"
  ],
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin()]
  },
  plugins: [
  ],
  output: {
    library: {
      name: 'a',
      type: 'umd'
    },
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

If you will use typescript compiler to generate declaration with paths/aliases you will get a d.ts file like this:

```
import { AliasClass } from "@alias";
export declare class A {
    private readonly aliasClass;
    do(): AliasClass;
}
```

It seems like TypeScript compiler doesn't use this transformation:

```
"plugins": [
      {
        "transform": "typescript-transform-paths",
        "afterDeclarations": true
      }
    ]
```

Do apply those transformations you need to install [ts-patch](https://github.com/nonara/ts-patch) and it works!

```
import { AliasClass } from "./alias-folder/index";
export declare class A {
    private readonly aliasClass;
    do(): AliasClass;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Updated answer from 2021**

No, we can’t have path alias resolved in declaration files. `ttsc` used to be an option, but it’s not being maintained for 2 years, and the newest version of `ttsc` doesn’t look compatible with TypeScript 4 and beyond. See this [issue](https://github.com/cevek/ttypescript/issues/122).

Writing the relative path is still the only way to go on TypeScript package developments, as the TypeScript team is still declining to have this supported officially on `tsc`.

Comment: I'm succesfully using ttsc with 4.4.4, and translating paths, so you are definitely wrong that it cannot be done.